# Save dataset data to other database

Tags: c#, .net

I have dataset connected with db. Dataset and TableAdapterManager were auto-created  by VS based on connection.

I can do like `this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(testcheckerDataSet);`
It's working fine.

Next I (using 3d party database editor) have copied .db file to "blank_testing.db" (2nd db) and then deleted all data from it. So It has just scheme without data.

Now I (in the code) filled dataset with data from "testchecker.db" (1st db), changed data using from elements and want to save data to 2nd db and then to 1st db. I try to make it chaging connectionString for each adapter.

```
string originalPath = tableAdapterManager.Connection.ConnectionString;

       string ns = tableAdapterManager.Connection.ConnectionString.Replace("testchecker.db", "blank_testing.db");

        tableAdapterManager.Connection.ConnectionString = ns;
        group_testingTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = ns;
        groupsTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = ns;
        testingTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = ns;


       this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll((testcheckerDataSet) testcheckerDataSet.Copy() ); // here error


        tableAdapterManager.Connection.ConnectionString = originalPath;
        group_testingTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = originalPath;
        groupsTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = originalPath;
        testingTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = originalPath;

this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll( testcheckerDataSet );
```

But I get error "concurrency violation the updatecommand affected 0 from 1". I think It happens because 2nd db has not data at all.

So could somebody advise me how can I save current dataset to another db file and then again to first (original) db?

Thanks.

Comment: Depending on the amount of data needing to me moved, I'd be tempted to use SqlBulkCopy for this. Have a read over - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

Comment: Adapters are not expensive. Just create new instances. And just copy records to a new Table.

Answer (score 2):

Problem here is when you call `UpdateAll` method it try to find previous record from database and update. but here in second db there is no record. what you can try is iterate through all the DataRows in your `DataTable` and use the `DataRow.SetAdded()` method to change the row's `DataRowState`, then it will consider records as newly added.

**One more thing:**
`SetAdded` can only be invoked on a `DataRow` instance where the `RowState` is `Unchanged`. you can call `AcceptChanges` on the `DataSet`. Then `RowState` property of each `DataRow` also changes; Added and Modified rows become Unchanged, and Deleted rows are removed. Now you can call `DataRow.SetAdded()`.

Comment: Thanks. It's working fine. But note one thing. 

Before calling `Row.SetAdded()` in cycle, we need call `DataSet.AcceptChanges()` for 2nd dataset, because data were mordified in the form as I mentioned initially. Else It will throw error "SetAdded and SetModified can only be called on DataRows with Unchanged DataRowState."

Comment: @PortnyaginMikhail yes, glad to hear it help you some way. updated my answer with your findings as well.